# Value of different portfolios

Tags: finance

> Suppose in the following portfolios all options are based on the same stock, have expiry date $T$ and strike price $K$ (unless otherwise stated). In each case find the portfolio value at time $T$ in terms of $S_T , K$:
>
> 1. one call option and one put option;
> 2. two call options and one share sold (i.e. short);
> 3. one share, short one call option;
> 4. one $(K_1,T)$ call option, short one $(K_2,T)$ put option.

For the first portfolio, I got $$\max(K-S_T,S_T-K)$$

For the second portfolio, I have $$\max(2(S_T - K),0)-S_0$$

For the last two I am really unsure and would be happy about your help.

Answer (score 1):

For portfolio 3:

$$(S_T-S_0) - max(S_T - K,0)$$

For portfolio 4:
$$ max(S_T-K_1,0) - max(K_2-S_T,0)$$

Also, I believe Portfolio 2 should be:
$$max(2(S_T - K),0)-(S_T-S_0)$$

Also, all of these valuations ignore any financing benefit/costs.